# How to iterate through entities in EF Core migration?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.1

I am retrofitting *Identity* into an existing project. I already had `Users`, `Roles`, and `UserRoles` tables, so it's mainly a matter or adjusting the table and column names before actually adding *Identity* classes, so they "take over" those tables.

The problem I have is as following. `UserEntity.Id` is a `Guid`, so I need to inherit `UserEntity` from `IdentityUser<Guid>`. But `RoleEntity.Id` is a `long`. *Identity* has that strange limitation, that `User.Id` and `Role.Id` types must match - at least when used in `AddIdentity<>` extension method. So I need to change the type of `RoleEntity.Id` to be `Guid`. And as I already have a number of users with roles, I have to adjust `UserRoles` table.

Now, creating new set of *Id*s for `Roles` is not a problem, they are seeded, so I merely created a new column `Roles.NewId` of type `Guid` and filled it with some random values. I also created a corresponding column `UserRoles.NewRoleId` (I will rename them in another migration before applying *Identity* so they match it). What I want is when *this particular* migration runs, the values from `Roles.NewId` are copied to `UserRoles.NewRoleId`, correspondingly to the existing allocations.

The SQL command could look like

```
UPDATE UserRoles U SET NewRoleId = (SELECT NewId FROM Roles WHERE Roles.Id = U.RoleId)
```

But I am using in-memory database (*SQLite*) for testing and *MariaDb* in production, so the SQL might not match. I already had some problems due to this setup, but there is no in-memory provider for *MariaDb*. Thus I would feel safer if I could insert the following loop somewhere:

```
foreach (var ur in UserRoles)
{
  ur.NewRoleId = Roles.First(r => r.Id == ur.RoleId).NewId;
}
Save();
```

Now:

1. Where can I insert that loop, so it only gets executed after this migration, and not after every single one?
2. How to handle the case that in the very next migration I will rename some columns, and later on I will drop the old `Id` and `RoleId` columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having investigated this, I found only two options.

1. Use SQL. It's not clean, there is no *IntelliSense*, but it'll work.
2. For this particular case, the roles are seeded, so `role id`s are known at compile time. Thus it is possible to abuse `migrationBuilder.UpdateData` by creating one call for each role and putting a new `Guid` (pre-generated and hard-coded) there.

```
migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
    table: "UserRoles",
    keyColumn: "RoleId",
    keyValue: 1L,
    column: "NewRoleId",
    value: new Guid("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"));
```